# Bringing a div to :active state via jquery .trigger() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have assigned to a div an `:active` CSS pseudo class, to make it "responsive" on clicks and holds.

```
   .quarter:active{
      opacity: 0.5;
   }
```

What I want to achieve is to simulate a long click with JQuery. 
The `.trigger("click")` doesn't seem to do the trick since there is no visible discoloration. I have also tried with `.trigger("focus")` and `.trigger("mousedown")` but it seems I mess up somewhere.

```
    <div id="1" class="quarter green" ></div>
    <div id="2" class="quarter red" ></div>
    <div id="3" class="quarter yellow" ></div>
    <div id="4" class="quarter blue" ></div>
```

Is there a way to achieve that or do I have to use a `toggleClass` approach?

**Edit:** Thanks to *nashcheez* answer I solved my problem using the `.trigger("focus")` followed by a `setTimeout(...{ .blur() })`. 
Thank you all for the quick responses.

Comment: I would use a `toggleClass` approach, why not.

Comment: `:active` is mostly used with `a` and `button` not sure if it would work with `div`

Comment: how about using selector:     .quarter:active,.quarter.active   ?

Comment: This question would probably easier to answer when you add a bit more information like: Why do you need a "mousehold" event in JS and what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Yes this definitely works with `:active`

Comment: It works well as it is... see here: https://jsfiddle.net/oaLndvs8/

Comment: @LcSalazar It works well as is when the user clicks, but not when I try to trigger a click with JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without `jQuery` and in pure `css`. You can just provide it a `focus` state in css and a `tabindex` attribute in the html.

Refer code:

```css
.quarter {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quarter:focus {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="quarter green" tabindex="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="quarter red" tabindex="1"></div>
<div id="3" class="quarter yellow" tabindex="1"></div>
<div id="4" class="quarter blue" tabindex="1"></div>
```

This way your `opacity` persists on click of the `div`, and returns back to the normal value on clicking anywhere outside.

Read more about the `tabindex` attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Answer (score 2):

Generally, [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) can be applied to `<a>` or `<button>` elements (as they are clickable), to make a `div` `:active` first you need to click on div it, then will be in **:active** state, also in the same case you can use `:focus` on this element to show as active.
Second option you can use `active` class and add it on particular `div`.

See the below snippet with its working.

```js
$('.quarter.green').trigger('focus');
```

```css
.quarter:active,
.quarter:focus,
.quarter.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: red;
}

.quarter:active {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="quarter green" contenteditable="true">1 Using contenteditable property</div>
<div id="2" class="quarter red active">2 Using active class</div>
<div id="3" class="quarter yellow">3</div>
<div id="4" class="quarter blue">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case  you want to use toogleclass with transitions this can work

```js
$('.quarter').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.quarter:active, .active{
      opacity: 0.5;
      transition: 1s all ease-in;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="quarter green" >green</div>
    <div id="2" class="quarter red" >red</div>
    <div id="3" class="quarter yellow" >yellow</div>
    <div id="4" class="quarter blue" >blue</div>
```